# Html how to style tfoot only on last page of print screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

The idea is to place a div on all footers except the last one when printing. If the print page has only one page, it will not show the div.

If you try to print and it has 2 pages, I would like the text "continue" to appear only on the first page. If there are too many pages show on all except the last one. If there is one page, don't show it.

How can I do that?

PS.: It needs to be on tfoot tag. I tried using JQuery to tag the footers that repeat but no success.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h1>Head</h1>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Teste</th>
                <td>Teste</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class='footer_continue'>continue --></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <h1>Footer</h1>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The first step is to separate the table into multiple tables. So you end up with a separate table per page. This is also really hard, because HTML content and a sheet of paper don't really go well together. You can use CSS to style your document with inches or centimeters, so that will help, but this is a pretty big task. You might try to generate a PDF instead, either server-side (fpdf) or in the browser (jspdf).

Comment: I thought that I could some how with css, tag the last "continue" since it - by nature - repeats on all print pages.

Comment: How do you plan to find out if the current page is the last page? Can this happen server-side (in that case, simply do not output the "continue" on the last page) or do you have to solve it client-side, like requesting the next page and checking if you get a 404 error?